# I'm getting column "my_column" contains null values' when adding a composite primary key

Tags: postgresql, database-migration

Is it not supposed to delete null values before altering the table? I'm confused...
My query looks roughly like this:

```sql
BEGIN;
    DELETE FROM my_table
      WHERE my_column IS NULL;

    ALTER TABLE my_table DROP CONSTRAINT my_table_pk;
    ALTER TABLE my_table ADD PRIMARY KEY (id, my_column);

    -- this is to repopulate the data afterwards
    INSERT INTO my_table (name, other_table_id, my_column)
    SELECT
        ya.name,
        ot.id,
        my_column
    FROM other_table ot
    
    LEFT JOIN yet_another ya
        ON ya.id = ot."fileId"
        
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 
            1
        FROM my_table mt
      WHERE  ot.id = mt.other_table_id AND ot.my_column = mt.my_column
  ) AND  my_column IS NOT NULL;
COMMIT;
```

sorry for naming

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible explanations:

- A concurrent session inserted a new row with a NULL value between the start of the `DELETE` and the start of `ALTER TABLE`.

  To avoid that, lock the table in `SHARE` mode before you `DELETE`.
- There is a row where `id` has a NULL value.

Comment: Thank you for answering!

Comment: If it's the first one, how do I get around this?

Comment: I told you in my answer -  take a share lock on the table.

Comment: Sorry, missed that somehow, thank you again